# Symfony ajax Response but with headers: HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date

Tags: php, ajax, http, symfony, header

i'm in troubles with Symfony and an ajax call.

I'm in Local server on Windows 8 with XAMPP 1.8.2.

Every works good, but when i take response i have this, below the right text:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 14:58:18
```

Why?

My codes:

In HTML (Twig) at the bottom:

```
$.ajax({
url: "{{ path('score') }}",
data: { id: scoreid, value: value },
dataType: 'json',
type: 'POST',
success: function (data) {
    if(data.responseCode==200 ){           
    $('#score').html(data.score);
    $('#score').css("color","green");
            }
else if(data.responseCode==400){
    $('#score').html(data.score);
    $('#score').css("color","red");
     }
     else{
    alert("An unexpeded error occured.");
    $('#score').html(data);
      }
            },
  error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
    $('#score').html('<span style="color:red">Error!</span>');
     }
});
```

Controller "score":

```
class scoreController extends Controller
{

    public function onepointAction(Request $request) {

        ....some logical...

            $points = self::pointsAction($id);

            $return=array("responseCode"=>200, "score"=>"Score: ".$num.".", "goal"=>"".$points);
        }

        else {

            $return=array("responseCode"=>400, "score"=>"No good!");
        }

        $return = json_encode($return);
        return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
    }

    public function pointsAction($id) {

        ......some logical query... ended by:
            ->getQuery();

        $pointsOk = $query->getResult();

        $avgScore = $avgScore[0]["score_avg"];

        $numScore = $avgPoints[0]["score_count"];

        $points = ("Scores: ".$avgScore."Goals: ".$numScore);

        return new Response($points);
    }
}
```

Where I make error?

Comment: hi @ginolin ! what is $num in this line : `$return=array("responseCode"=>200, "score"=>"Score: ".$num.".", "goal"=>"".$points);` ! can you post a dump of $points before the $return ?

Comment: Dump of `$points` (`pointsAction`) is this: `string(53) "Scores: 5.8021Goals: 96"` There aren't headers in dump. I put `var_dump` before `return new Response($points);` and i take it not from the same twig of the first controller, I take it from a simple path only for `pointsAction` Controller.

Comment: Your code seems really correct, as far as you used `json` value in `dataType` parameter. Try using the `JsonResponse` in your controller's action. In my case i used this class.

Comment: Try to have a look also at `JSONStringfy` to convert `data` in json without using the `dataType` parameter

Comment: I found the solution to my big problem:

`->getContent()` at the end of $points = `self::pointsAction($id);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution to my big problem:

`->getContent()` at the end of $points = `self::pointsAction($id);`

Answer (score 1):

It's quite normal as you're rendering a full "Response" object, which contains headers too.

What you see as

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 14:58:18
```

are the headers contained in the controller answer.

If you want to render JSon directly you should then consider using the `JSonResponse` object instead of the `Response` one. (FQCN : `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse` )

Comment: Dear friend @YoannCh, I change my code with: `//$return = json_encode($return); //return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json')); return new JsonResponse($return);` but I take the same headers (also with: `Content-Type application/json`). Also with this changed code in `pointsAction controller`. How can it be?

Comment: I get the point : what happens if you just use the `return $return`? (or `return $points`)

Comment: If I put simple return $points in `pointsAction` I get this error from Symfony: `The controller must return a response`. If I put simple return in `onepointAction Controller` I get error from Ajax `error: function (jxhr, msg, err)`.

Comment: Du you use annotations on your controller actions such as `@Template` ?

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, this is what he meant:

```
return response()->json([
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message,
        ], 200)->getContent();
```